# Traveling to UK for different reasons than I initially got the visa for

Tags: uk, standard-visitor-visas, change-purpose-of-travel

I applied for the visa to participate in a university students conference. But I had to cancel my travel plans because of a family emergency.

I wanted to know if I can still can use the multiple entry Visa I have, until it expires, to enter UK for a similar type of conference and business related travel reasons or if I have to apply again to enter UK for the different reason of travel other than I applied for initially.

Comment: UK visitor visas are routinely issued as multiple entry and with a 6 month validity period. That doesn’t necessarily mean you can use it for a completely different purpose / length of stay / number of entries to that stated in your original application. It depends to what extent the change of plan constitutes a material change of circumstances. See https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82916/holiday-visit-to-uk-with-a-c-visit-visa-which-i-got-for-a-business-trip-that-nev/82925#82925

Answer (score 4):

As long as what you are doing is permitted by the type of visa, there is no problem. By giving you a multiple entry visa they clearly indicated you were permitted (even expected) to use the visa more then once, and that not all the uses were going to be for this conference.

It's just possible you may be asked why you didn't go to the conference,  but assuming you have a reasonable reason it will be OK.