# Change of purpose of UK visit After Getting the UK Standard Visitor Visa

Tags: visas, uk, customs-and-immigration, standard-visitor-visas

I applied for a UK Visitor Visa and got my visa. I was going to participate in a two day training course at Cambridge University. But due to some issues with the course, I would not like to participate in the course this time.

As I purchased my two way flight ticket already, is it possible to use my ticket for tourist purposes (sightseeing in London) only instead of participating in the course?

During the Landing interview, should I mention this issue? Should I provide the new hotel reservation and is it enough?

Comment: Your case is similar to this one
https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/131468/traveling-to-uk-for-different-reasons-than-i-initially-got-the-visa-for

Comment: Are you planning to stay significantly longer than you stated in your original application? Related question re change of circumstances https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82916/holiday-visit-to-uk-with-a-c-visit-visa-which-i-got-for-a-business-trip-that-nev/82925#82925

Answer (score 1):

UK visitor visas are routinely issued as multiple entry and with a 6 month validity period. That doesn’t necessarily mean you can use it for a completely different purpose / length of stay / number of entries to that stated in your original application. It depends to what extent the change of plan constitutes a material change of circumstances. See [Holiday visit to UK with a C-Visit visa which I got for a business trip that never happened; meantime I left the company that backed my application](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/82916/holiday-visit-to-uk-with-a-c-visit-visa-which-i-got-for-a-business-trip-that-nev/82925#82925)

You could ask the Embassy/Consulate that issued your visa whether your change of plan is acceptable and take evidence of their reply with you to the UK. If you decide to rely solely on a successful landing interview, your best course is always to tell the truth and have paperwork to prove it. Eg if you had leave of absence from your employer for the course, get a new one for vacation purposes. And take your original paperwork with you.